# display table row data in bootstrap 4 modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to display table row `td` data in bootstrap 4 modal after click on `show data` link.

html:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-title="title">test</td>
          <td data-title="size">14</td>
          <td data-title="attribute">-</td>
          <td data-title="height">120</td>
          <td data-title="price">4000</td>
          <td data-title="action"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailsModal" href="javascript:void(0);">show data</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td data-title="title">test1</td>
          <td data-title="size">12</td>
          <td data-title="attribute">-</td>
          <td data-title="height">150</td>
          <td data-title="price">6000</td>
          <td data-title="action"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailsModal" href="javascript:void(0);">show data</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#detailsModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      var _button = $(e.relatedTarget);
      var $row = $(_button).closest("tr"); // Find the row
      var $tds = $row.find("td");
      $.each($tds, function() {
        var t = $(this).attr('data-title');
        var v = $(this).text();
        var result = ('<div>'+ t + ' : ' + v + '</div>'); // error
      });
      console.log(result);
      $(this).find(".container").html(result);
    });
  });
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="detailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailsModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In action when I click on link I see this error in console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined

how do can I fix this error?!

DEMO [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbmwf65/)

Comment: Just some typos . Working code check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6ayh7urt/) .

Comment: @Swati: Oh, you right. but I see `undefined` on top of `modal` or `console`.

Comment: there was mistake on my end change `var result` to `var result="";` and try again  . Updated [code](https://jsfiddle.net/2wxueamn/)

Comment: thanks that's working now, please add your codes in answer.

Comment: You already have one answer which tells you what problem was there in your current code so you can accept that answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Swati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10606400/swati) solved my question in comment:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#detailsModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      var _button = $(e.relatedTarget);
      var result="";
      var $row = $(_button).closest("tr"); // Find the row
      var $tds = $row.find("td");
      $.each($tds, function() {
        var t = $(this).attr('data-title');
        var v = $(this).text();
         result += '<div>'+ t + ' : ' + v + '</div>';
      });
      console.log(result);
      $(this).find("#container").html(result);
    });
  });
```

Demo: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2wxueamn/)

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like it's happening not at the place where you have the comment, but rather on the `console.log` statement you have outside your loop. Since you're declaring result inside that loop, that's the only place where it will be defined.

If you're looking to concatenate results on each `td` and spit out the whole thing, you'll need to do a `let result` before the loop starts.

Comment: Hi, just add some code as well in your answer to make it complete .